# How to verify a chrome tab URL by using UI-Automator?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am working on one application which launches chrome browser with some url,i want to verify whether chrome launched and it opened whatever url i have sent.I want to test this application using ui automator,how can i access chrome package and check tab url.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect chrome to be up with the page in view, it would be something like:

```
UiObject urlbar = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar"));
String url = urlbar.getText();
```

That assumes Chrome is open though.  If you wanted to also automate the application then you'd need to know the button IDs you want to click, the text box you enter the url in, etc.  The basic steps are the same as above though.  Create a UiObject by using a UiSelector to find the thing on screen you want to interact with.  Here is a link to UiAutomators documentation: [UiAutomator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume on click of a button you're trying to navigate to "https://www.abcd.com/xyz". 
(This URL is not valid. This is just a sample)

Steps to follow:

1. **Initialise UiSelector and UiDevice in your test class** : 
    private val select = UiSelector() 
    private val device = 
    UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
2. **Click on the button** : onView(withId(id)).perform(click())
3. **Find the resource id** : 
    val urlBar = device.findObject(select.resourceId("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar"))
4. **Assert the Navigation** : assert(urlBar.text.contains("xyz"))